# add referrer to woo

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

we just moved from Shopify to Woo and wanted to add a custom field "referrer" to an order, to track our ads.

I found this article, but somehow does not manage to make it work. maybe it is a bit outdated?

https://blog.stevenkellow.com/add-referrer-info-to-woocommerce-order/

```
2019-02-27T10:30:22+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few 

arguments to function add_referral_meta(), 1 passed in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 2 expected in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/themes/woondershop-pt-child/functions.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): add_referral_meta(6758)
#1 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(367): do_action('woocommerce_che...', 6758, Array)
#4 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(1067): WC_Checkout->create_order(Array)
#5 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(334): WC_Checkout->process_checkout()
#6 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286) in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/themes/woondershop-pt-child/functions.php in Zeile 47

2019-02-27T10:31:42+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function add_referral_meta(), 1 passed in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 2 expected in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/themes/woondershop-pt-child/functions.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): add_referral_meta(6760)
#1 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(367): do_action('woocommerce_che...', 6760, Array)
#4 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(1067): WC_Checkout->create_order(Array)
#5 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(334): WC_Checkout->process_checkout()
#6 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286) in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/themes/woondershop-pt-child/functions.php in Zeile 47

2019-02-27T11:46:53+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function add_referral_meta(), 1 passed in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 2 expected in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/themes/woondershop-pt-child/functions.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): add_referral_meta(6762)
#1 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(367): do_action('woocommerce_che...', 6762, Array)
#4 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(1067): WC_Checkout->create_order(Array)
#5 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(334): WC_Checkout->process_checkout()
#6 /www/myshop_210/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286) in /www/myshop_210/public/wp-content/themes/woondershop-pt-child/functions.php in Zeile 52
```

I did not find another newer version or plugin.. Could any of you help me out?

thanks,
E.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the original article is broken, and would've been broken when it was written. So being outdated is not the problem (2 years is nothing in WordPress time).

The issue is this line:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_referral_meta');
```

The callback function they've created, `add_referral_meta()`, accepts two arguments, `$order_id` and `$posted`:

```
function add_referral_meta( $order_id, $posted ) {
```

But if a callback function accepts more than one argument, the `add_action()` call needs to specify how many. So that first line of code needs to look like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_referral_meta', 10, 2 );
```

You can read more about how actions work in WordPress in the [developer documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/).

That being said, this isn't a future-proof solution, since it's not using the proper WooCommerce methods for saving order meta. I suggest using this code instead:

```
function wpse_330106_set_origin_cookie() {
    $cookie_value = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if ( ! is_admin() && ! isset( $_COOKIE['origin'] ) ) {
        setcookie( 'origin', $cookie_value, time() + 3600*24*30, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_330106_set_origin_cookie');

function wpse_330106_add_order_referrer( $order ) {
    $order->add_meta_data( 'referrer', $_COOKIE['origin'] );
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'wpse_330106_add_order_referrer', 10, 1 );
```

This solution uses the more modern `$order->add_meta_data()` method, which is the current proper way to add meta data to WooCommerce orders these days. This is because it will continue to work regardless of where WooCommerce stores its order data. This will be useful when WooCommerce inevitable starts storing orders in a custom table, rather than as posts.

Comment: cool thanks! where would I find the referrer now? I did not see anything in the meta of the order! thanks .. but at least it is not broken anymore :)

Comment: It's in the database, but it doesn't look like that article has any information on displaying it anywhere. Where did you want it to appear?

Comment: ahh i see. I just googled the Function the guy used and found out, that it will appear in the order in the backend. that's where I hoped to find it. plus in the API :)

Comment: which table would that be and do I get the information also from the API? thanks!

Comment: can you help me here? thanks!@jacob peattie